# C# Windows form application - Save configuration during installation / Use external config

Tags: c#, mysql, xml, windows, desktop-application

Before I begin, I've done good bit of research and googling. I think I didn't find the perfect answer because I'm probably a noob :)

However, I've created a POS software using Windows C# form application and it's working perfectly fine. Now, this application is using MySQL as database server.

I've been hard-coding the database server credentials on app.config file.

Code for the app.config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="cString" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=adittoenterprise;port=3306;Uid=root;Pwd=root123" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Now I'm trying to create a package for other users to use. Definitely I need to come up with solution where the user can provide

host
username
password

During the installation and the application should store this somewhere (that is where my knowledge is lacking) and use it on the run time.

Any alternative solution is most welcome.

Thanks everyone in advance for bearing with me and helping me :)

Answer (score 2):

Your installer needs to modify the app.config file.  There are many different types of installers available and some of the more fully-featured packages can modify XML files such as app.config during installation.

It's also possible to modify the connection string at runtime (though since it's an application-scope setting, not a user-scope setting, that's probably not a good idea) as long as you do it before any database objects attempt to use it:

```
Properties.Settings.Default["cString"] = "new connection string";
```

... so you could potentially distribute your app.config with a blank connection string and prompt the user to provide those values the first time the application is run.  You'd have to save the new value into a user-scope setting, though, in order for Save() to work:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.CustomConnectionString = "new connection string";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

(Note that I am a computer science student and still learning)

EDIT the links are not useful for your case as they only work with IIS, but still I would not save passwords in plaintext to a file such as the other answer suggested.

It should be considered bad practice to save the password especially plain text. Usually if an application starts it would require the user to authenticate to get access to the database. Of course you can store the password, but doing that properly you should look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh8x3tas.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Then if your application start for the first time your application can create/edit the config file and store the values. Note that your application cannot change it's own app.config at runtime so it would make sense to create a web.config for you database connection.